# Attoparsec `many` method not found

Tags: haskell, attoparsec

I tried running the tests for Bryan O'Sullivan's Attoparsec-based HTTP parser (http://www.serpentine.com/blog/2010/03/03/whats-in-a-parser-attoparsec-rewired-2/), and I got this error:

```
> runhaskell TestRFC2616.hs

TestRFC2616.hs:13:30:
    Not in scope: `many'
    Perhaps you meant one of these:
      `any' (imported from Prelude),
      `B.any' (imported from Data.ByteString.Char8),
      many' (imported from Data.Attoparsec)
```

Surprised, I ran ghci and got this:

```
> ghci
GHCi, version 7.6.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Prelude> :m +Data.Attoparsec
Prelude Data.Attoparsec> :t many

<interactive>:1:1:
    Not in scope: `many'
    Perhaps you meant one of these:
      `any' (imported from Prelude),
      many' (imported from Data.Attoparsec),
      `many1' (imported from Data.Attoparsec)
Prelude Data.Attoparsec>
```

Can anyone tell me what's going on?

Comment: `many'`, not `many`. And you probably want `Control.Applicative`'s `many`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example is 4 years old. In version 0.8.0 there was a implementation of `many` in the `Data.Attoparsec.Combinator` module, you can check the source [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/attoparsec/0.8.0.0/doc/html/src/Data-Attoparsec-Combinator.html#many).

The current version of the library doesn't implements a `many` function, but it implements a `many'` function (source [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/attoparsec/0.10.4.0/doc/html/src/Data-Attoparsec-Combinator.html#many%27)). That's why you `ghci` give you `many'` as a suggestion.

The `many` that was implemented in `Data.Attoparsec.Combinator` is the same that is implemented in `Control.Applicative` (see [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.2.0.0/doc/html/src/Control-Applicative.html#%28line97%29) the implementation of `many` in the `Alternative` type class). You probably need to `import` the `Control.Applicative`. If that works I would suggest that you make a pull request to solve that issue (the library repository is [here](https://github.com/bos/attoparsec))